# Problem in citing a specific author

Tags: biblatex, mla-style

I am trying to cite the work done by Lotif A. Zadeh in my thesis containing 5 chapters. The following is the Bibtex entry:

```
@article{Zadeh1965,
author = {Zadeh, L. A.},
journal = {Information and Control},
number = {3},
pages = {338--353},
title = {{Fuzzy Sets}},
volume = {8},
year = {1965}
}
```

My original code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.png}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb} % for mathematical formulas
\usepackage{rotating} %used to have landskape figures
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
%\usepackage{algorithms}
%\usepackage{makeidx}
%\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e,array,booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[square]{natbib}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\let\bibhang\relax
\let\citename\relax
\let\bibfont\relax
\let\Citeauthor\relax
\expandafter\let\csname ver@natbib.sty\endcsname\relax
\makeglossary
\usepackage[style=mla, firstlonghand=false, backend=bibtex, showmedium=false, guessmedium=false]{biblatex}



   % to have links to figures and citations in PDF version.
\usepackage{hyperref}

%\usepackage{setspace}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Bibliography}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\pagestyle{headings}  % to get running heads
\makeindex
\bibliography{BibPhdNew}


%------------------------- Document settings ------------------------
\setlength{\textheight}{245mm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{160mm}

\setlength{\headheight}{3mm}
\setlength{\headsep}{12mm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{15mm}
% left side empty space on odd- & even-numbered pages
\if@twoside
\typeout{Two side is true}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{30mm}  % for two side printing
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{20mm}
\else
\typeout{Two side is false}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{30mm}  % for one side printing
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{30mm} % odd side margin = even side margin
\fi
\setlength{\hoffset}{-1in} % already accounted for in the margins
\setlength{\voffset}{-1in} % already accounted for in the margins
% line, paragraphs indent & spacing
\setlength{\parindent}{5ex} % indentation 5 characters approx.

%------------------------- Definitions ------------------------------

\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\alph{enumi}} % to get alphabets in enumerated lists
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\arabic{enumii}} % to get numbers in level-2 enumerated lists
%\renewcommand{\thetable}{\Roman{table}} % to get table numbers in capital roman
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Chapter}
\renewcommand{\textwidth}{6in}
\newcommand{\pic}[2]{\setlength{\epsfysize}{#1} \epsffile{#2}}
%------------------------- document ---------------------------------

\begin{document}
% --------- Title and abstract etc the front matter -----------
\pagenumbering{roman}
%\input{coverpages}
%\begin{singlespace}


\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abbreviations}\label{Abbreviations}
\input{Abbreviations}

%\end{singlespace}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

% ----------------- thesis chapters -----------

\flushbottom
\include{Chapter1}
\flushbottom
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
\flushbottom
\include{Chapter2}
\flushbottom
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
\flushbottom
\include{Chapter3}
\flushbottom
%------------------------------------------------------------------------
\flushbottom
\include{Chapter4}
\flushbottom
%------------------------------------------------------------------------
\flushbottom
\include{Chapter5}
\flushbottom
%------------------------------------------------------------------------
\flushbottom
\include{Chapter6}
\flushbottom

% ------------ Bibliography---------------
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
\printbibliography

\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index} 
\printindex

% ------------ Appendix ----------------

%\appendix
%%------------------------------------------------------------------------
%\flushbottom
%\include{AppendixA}
%\flushbottom
%%------------------------------------------------------------------------
%\flushbottom
%\include{AppendixB}
%\flushbottom
%------------------------------------------------------------------------



\end{document}


%\cite{label}
```

The text where I want to use the above mentioned bibliography appears in Chapter2 and is **The concept of fuzzy logic was advanced by Dr. Lotfi Zadeh of the University of California at Berkely in 1965 \cite{Zadeh1965}.**

The citation appears as Zadeh, "Fuzzy Sets" in the pdf. I have tried different combinations and have noticed that if I misspell the author's name as Zade, Zadet and Hadeh then the citation appears perfectly in the pdf. Only when I use the spelling 'Zadeh', I get incorrect citation in the pdf. This is repeating twice in my pdf. Please help me to rectify the error.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) We cannot help you in finding the error in code we do not know. So please add a [minimal but working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography) to your question.

Comment: A MWEB would be really helpful! Just a guess: do you cite other works by the same author in the same year?

Comment: I have cited other works of the same author but not in the same year.

Comment: Can you explain what the expected output would be like? What is wrong about the current output? Please show us a full example [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) that allows us to reproduce the output you get. A solution crucially depends on the your bibliography package and style.

Comment: Any news here? It is not entirely clear to me what your question is. And even it was clear to me, without an MWE that shows how you create the bibliography there is hardly a way to solve your problem without wild guessing.

Comment: I have added the MWEB. I am working on my thesis which will have 6 chapters. I have the main file containing all the packages, documents, page-settings and other things. I am currently working on Chapter 2 wherein I need to cite the above-mentioned work.

Comment: That is by no means an MWE, an MWE should allow us to reprduce your problem with as few lines of code as possible. Your code does not compile out of the box for us, since we don't have all your `\include`'d files. It also does not show the issue because you don't cite anything in the code you have shown us. It contains way too much other stuff that is not at all helpful to investigate your problem.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `biblatex-mla`. And the output you get if you don't have another work by Zadeh is just 'Zadeh'. As soon as there are at least two works by the same author you will get the title to disambiguate the two sources.

Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=mla, firstlonghand=false, backend=bibtex, showmedium=false, guessmedium=false]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Zadeh1965,
author = {Zadeh, L. A.},
journal = {Information and Control},
number = {3},
pages = {338--353},
title = {{Fuzzy Sets}},
volume = {8},
year = {1965}
}
@online{bronto,
  author  = {Anne Elk},
  title   = {Towards a Unified Theory on Brontosauruses},
  date    = {1972-11-16},
  url     = {http://example.edu/~elk/bronto.pdf},
  urldate = {2015-09-07},
}
@book{title,
  author = {Elk, Anne},
  title  = {Title},
  volume = {1},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{bronto}

\cite{Zadeh1965}

\cite{title}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Where the two works by Elk are disambiguated by the title, and there is only one work by Zadeh which does then not get a title.

This is an integral part of the style you use. If you don't want that, you should seriously consider using a different style.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It makes sense to me now. I will have to continue with the style as it is the requirement of my university.